# Get value new custom field in variations product Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good day! I created new custom filed in variations product Woocommerce! How do get value this field for use him in other function?

In General I need to pass a value from one function to another is it possible to do this at all ?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'num_cubicmeters_fields', 10, 3 );
function num_cubicmeters_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'                => '_num_cubic_var[' . $variation->ID . ']', // id поля
        'label'             => 'Количество кубометров', // Надпись над полем
        'description'       => 'Укажи количество кубометров',// Описание поля
        'desc_tip'          => 'true', // Всплывающая подсказка
        'placeholder'       => 'Количество кубометров, м3', // Надпись внутри поля
        'type'              => 'number', // Тип поля
        'custom_attributes' => array( // Произвольные аттрибуты
            'step' => 'any', // Шаг значений
            'min'  => '0', // Минимальное значение
        ),
        'value'             => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, '_num_cubic_var', true ),
    ) );
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'art_save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
function art_save_variation_settings_fields( $post_id ) {
    $woocommerce__num_cubic_var = $_POST['_num_cubic_var'][ $post_id ];
    if (isset($woocommerce__num_cubic_var) && ! empty( $woocommerce__num_cubic_var ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_num_cubic_var', esc_attr( $woocommerce__num_cubic_var ) );
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' );
function load_variation_settings_fields( $variations ) {
    $variations_num_cubic = get_post_meta( $variations['variation_id'], '_num_cubic_var', true );
    if ( isset( $variations_num_cubic ) && ! empty( $variations_num_cubic ) ) {
        $variations['_num_cubic_var'] = '<div class="num-cubicmeters-prod">';
        $variations['_num_cubic_var'] .= '<span>Количество Кубометров</span>';
        $variations['_num_cubic_var'] .= get_post_meta( $variations['variation_id'], '_num_cubic_var', true ) . ' м3';
        $variations['_num_cubic_var'] .= '</div>';
    }

    return $variations;
}



function ut_before_calculate_totals( $cart_obj ) {

////    global $product;
////    echo '<pre>';
////        var_dump($product);
////    echo '</pre>';
//
//    $meta = get_post_meta();
//    var_dump($meta);


//    $variations_num_cubic = get_post_meta( $variations['variation_id'], '_num_cubic_var', true );
//    var_dump($variations_num_cubic);



    foreach( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {

        $product_total_price = ( !empty( get_post_meta( $value['data']->get_id(), '_sale_price', true) ) ) ? get_post_meta( $value['data']->get_id(), '_sale_price', true) : get_post_meta( $value['data']->get_id(), '_regular_price', true);
        $volume = ( isset( $value['variation']['attribute_m-3-na-poddone'] ) ) ? $value['variation']['attribute_m-3-na-poddone'] : 1 ;
        $result_price = $product_total_price * $volume ;

        $value['data']->set_price( $result_price );

    }
}
```

[function create field](http://pastebin.com/vaAaaZiG)

[dunction for use field](http://pastebin.com/ca6avSX8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```php
function ut_before_calculate_totals( $cart_obj ) {
    foreach( $cart_obj->get_cart() as $key => $value ) {
        //echo '<pre>', print_r($value, 1), '</pre>';
        // The variation ID
        $variation_id = $value['data']->get_id();

        // output
        echo $variation_id . '<br>';

        // Get post meta
        $variations_num_cubic = get_post_meta( $variation_id, '_num_cubic_var', true );

        // output
        echo $variations_num_cubic . '<br>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'ut_before_calculate_totals', 10, 1 );
```